# OpenVPN doesn't forward HTTPS traffic, HTTP works fine

Tags: linux, networking, ip, tcp

I have an OpenVPN server running on a Raspberry Pi, and I'm encountering issues trying to connect to HTTPS sites using it. I can connect to HTTP sites (confirmed via `nc example.com 80`). From the Raspberry Pi itself (i.e. connected via SSH), I can access HTTPS sites (confirmed using `openssl s_client -connect`). From my laptop tunneling through the Pi, I can connect to HTTP sites (confirmed with `nc`). But if I try to use `openssl s_client` from my laptop, it just shows:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect www.xkcd.com:443
CONNECTED(00000003)
```

(i.e. it doesn't show any of the cipher information that `s_client` normally shows), and GET requests go unanswered.

`iptables` rules are:

```
# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Answer (score 4):

This seems to have been caused by an MTU issue, as described on [OpenVPN's FAQ.](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/271-i-can-ping-through-the-tunnel-but-any-real-work-causes-it-to-lock-up-is-this-an-mtu-problem) While I could do some simple HTTP tests, it failed when I attempted the (more complex) HTTPS connections. Adding `mssfix 1200` to the server config appears to have fixed it.